# Why does the Radiohead library's method for receiving an array of characters use pass-by-reference for array length?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I am using the Radiohead library in an Arduino sketch for sending and receiving transmissions at 433.92 MHz. The sketch I am using works and I am able to send and receive sensor data (temperature, humidity) embedded in character strings "on air". However, I am puzzled by an implementation detail.

The `recv()` method of the `RH_ASK` class for receiving messages takes two arguments. The first is a pointer to an array of characters. This is understandable as messages are sent and received as character arrays. The second is the length of the array. This is an integer-valued number which is also passed as a pointer. Isn't it more convenient to send the integer-valued number itself i.e. pass-by-value instead of pass-by-reference?

Here is the relevant code snippet modeled on the article [here](https://dronebotworkshop.com/433mhz-rf-modules-arduino/).

Include the library, create an instance of the receiver object and initialize it.

```
// Include RadioHead Amplitude Shift Keying Library
#include <RH_ASK.h>

// Create Amplitude Shift Keying Object
RH_ASK rf_driver;

// Initialize ASK Object
rf_driver.init();
```

Receive a stream of characters into buffer, convert to string and parse for sensor readings.

```
// Set buffer to size of expected message
uint8_t buf[11];
uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf);

// Check if received packet is correct size
if (rf_driver.recv(buf, &buflen)) // Why &buflen and not simply buflen?
{

   // Message received with valid checksum
   // Get values from string

   // Convert received data into string
   str_out = String((char*)buf);

   // Thereafter, parse the string to extract sensor readings,
   // and print them out.               
}
```

I'd appreciate any help understanding the concept behind passing a perfectly good integer by reference instead of value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the function needs to change the integer to the length of the received data.

https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/RadioHead/blob/e8581c127fac9bffb0ee800ae18847f673e9b4a5/RH_ASK.cpp#L462